# How do I read data from a Json file discord.py

Tags: json, discord.py, bots

How do I read data from a json file in a pyhton file

json file:

```json
    {
        "bot-token": "BotTokenHere",
        "OwnerDiscordName": "UsernameAndTag"
    }
```

I'm trying to get data from a file called **config.json** and put it into a python variable the python file is call **bot.py**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the file content through `json` lib:
import json

```
with open("config.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then you can acess the items by dict indexing:

```
token = data["bot-token"]
```